# psycopg2 expecting data for serial column in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using *copy_from* to copy data into a table in postgresql. It is trying to insert data into the serial column however (or complaining there is no data if the column is at the end)

I have a table created in postgresql as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE userdata (
    userid int4 null,
    activity varchar null,
    "time" timestamp null,
    id serial not null,
    primary key (id)
    );
```

I have a dataframe with columns 'userid', 'activity', 'time'
When I try to copy this into the table I get the error:

> "psycopg2.DataError: missing data for column "id"

I expect this column to be populated with the default value, which I can see in the properties of the column that it is set correctly to `nextval('userdata_id_seq'::regclass)`

Code I'm using for the data insertion:

```
output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep='|', index=False, header=False)

connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
output.seek(0)
cursor.copy_from(output, table, sep='|', null='')
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Am I missing some setting in my code or something?

Comment: Have you tried explictly specifying the columns that are present in the input? [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) state `If not specified, it is assumed that the entire table matches the file structure.`

Comment: thx, that seems to be working indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above by shmee in the comments, and in the docs,
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html
If the columns are specified in the pycopg2 copy_from statement, thus:
`cur.copy_from(f, 'test', columns=('num', 'data'))`
....but don't specify the serial column, then it will be incremented automatically.